# What is the value that needs to be passed to code_verifier

Tags: autodesk-forge

While following the below tutorial we see there is a field called code_verifier

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/

This field is not mentioned in documentation provided at  https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/gettoken-POST/

What needs to be passed in this field ?

Comment: This needs to be clarified in the documentation. Thank you for bringing it up Rahul. Btw you're looking at a very fresh version 2 of the Authentication service. If you're getting started, consider using v1: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v1/developers_guide/overview/.

Comment: is v2 still fresh? the docs are not consistent and at the moment the docs says: Random URL string using the unreserved characters with a minimum length of 43 characters and a maximum length of 128 characters. This is required if grant_type is authorization_code and code_challenge was specified in /authorize request.    What does it even mean? I'm getting constantly invalid_credentials error